# Update the certificates on Ubuntu 16.04 TLS

Tags: ssl, certificates

I have an impression that ca-certificates on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is outdated.

Today I tried to do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates -y
```

but none was updated:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (1.2.35).
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20210119~16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

Is my guess correct that Ubuntu 16.04 repository has outdated certificates?

If yes, how to install the latest ones?

(probably Git requires new certificates, see the full story [here](https://developernote.com/2021/12/server-certificate-verification-failed-error-with-command-line-git-client/))

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Don't forget you're using a release that reached EOL for *standard* support back in April (5 years after release), so unless you enabled ESM, upgrades stopped months ago and so having no updates on a release that reached EOL surprises you?  Only systems with ESM enabled receive updates now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your system was upgraded you'd be using the following package

[ca-certificates](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5089-2) `20210119~16.04.1ubuntu0.1~esm1`

But you've not updated your Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system, even though support ended in [April 2021](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/).  Why are you surprised?

If you want to continue using Ubuntu 16.04 ESM, enable ESM and get the upgraded packages.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS however is off-topic here.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic and you'll see only *supported* (*standard* or public) releases of Ubuntu are on-topic here.

Comment: FYI:  the package update/link I provided may not be the *latest*, I only looked for a notice of an upgrade for 16.04; and that was the first I found.