# Trying to upgrade but getting certificate error due to Jenkins

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, repository, certificates, jenkins

I am upgrading an old 16.04 LTS machine (yes, I know I'm stupid for waiting this long when it is EOL)

It seems to be a problem with Jenkins and/or its repositories

```
sudo apt-get update
```

gives me:

```
Err:23 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Packages
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Fetched 12.5 MB in 39s (313 kB/s)

Reading package lists... Done

W: The repository 'http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
.
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.docker.com_linux_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)

E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.docker.com_linux_ubuntu_dists_xenial_stable_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial Release
```

I've tried the following plus other things I don't remember:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-mark hold jenkins
```

editing the sources list and commenting out jenkins/docker stuff

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Deleting stuff out of `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/`

I've been trying for days.

Comment: You need to enable ESM before you can fully upgrade your 16.04 system and download the new certificates. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378534/update-the-certificates-on-ubuntu-16-04-tls/1378535#1378535

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: *"I've been trying for days"* - A new installation will take less than an hour from start to finish, so wouldn't it make a lot more sense to go that route?  If you insist on trying to upgrade this installation, it's important that any details you provide are complete. Please don't manipulate the output of commands.  Instead, copy/paste the entire output and use code fences. Don't cut out lines or add punctuation.