# Upgrade from ubuntu tls 14.04 to latest version (9/2023)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I have a 14.04 lts that says no new releases found.
after searching i found some pages about a certificate update etc.
Is there a manual with the commands to help me do that?
show new dependencies to the 14.04 so it can upgrade ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To upgrade CA certificates you'll need ESM (or Pro) *enabled* in order to download them, and no special command is required if you have that setup on your system. You can refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378534/update-the-certificates-on-ubuntu-16-04-tls for more detail (though it applies to 16.04 - which is where the upgrade will go to).  Community support has ended (*we're part of Community support*) for releases earlier than Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.